# artefact issue gdalogr:translate with python

Tags: raster, gdal, pyqgis, merge

I'm trying to merge one band rasters into one multiband raster using gdalogr:merge in python. The fact is that I get an artefact, a lots of my values are converted near 0, which does not appear when I'm doing it manually from QGIS GUI `(Raster-> Merge)`.

This is the histogram I get with the script
[image]

and this one manually...
[image]

my syntax in python :

```
outputs_GDALOGRMERGE_1=processing.runalg('gdalogr:merge', {"INPUT" :[blue,green,red,rededge,nir], "PCT" : False, "SEPARATE": True,"NODATA":0, "OUTPUT":"output_path"})
```

I tried using the algorithm a more classical way with

```
outputs_GDALOGRMERGE_1=processing.runalg('gdalogr:merge', [blue,green,red,rededge,nir],False,True,0,5,None)
```

But the same issue was happening and I thought maybe it came from the Float32 conversion, apparently not...

Answer (score 1):

Float32 conversion is used by default with **gdalogr:merge** (manually from QGIS GUI) so, I don't think that issue can come from this. However, when I print 'Processing Information' for 'gdalogr:merge' tool:

[image]

it can be observed that you apparently have an inexistent parameter ("NODATA":0) in first command and a wrong number of them in second one. I don't know why it produced a result but it could be origin of problem.

Try out following command:

```
outputs_GDALOGRMERGE_1=processing.runalg('gdalogr:merge', {"INPUT" :[blue,green,red,rededge,nir], "PCT" : False, "SEPARATE": True,"RTYPE":5, "OUTPUT":"output_path"})
```

or:

```
outputs_GDALOGRMERGE_1=processing.runalg('gdalogr:merge', {"INPUT" :[blue,green,red,rededge,nir], "PCT" : True, "SEPARATE": True,"RTYPE":5, "OUTPUT":"output_path"})
```

I hope that it helps.

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for the answer but unfortunately not :/ The nodata parameter comes from the fact that documentations are different depending on where you search... The batch doc of gdal merge here http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html contains a lot more parameters that are not available in the algorithm doc here https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_miscellaneous/merge.html ...

Comment: First one is not for processing tool (it is for running in console). Second one is exactly as in my answer. You shouldn't mix arbitrarily documentation. If you want to use **gdal_merge.py** in your code, instead processing, syntax is completely different.